# Retrieve non-mapped attribute from Active Directory using C# code in SharePoint 2013

Tags: development, sharepoint-on-prem

How can I retrieve a non-mapped attribute from active directory (like Birthday), in SharePoint 2013 using C# code?

With "non-mapped" I mean a property not synchronized with the user SharePoint profile

Comment: Do you want the attributes for current user?

Comment: what i mean is ,i want to retrieve data for those columns of active directory who is not have any mapped attribute,if you wil check then you will find that the birthday is not having this attribute and i want to fetch this value,so how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i resolved the issue by applying bellow code
code for retrieving current user

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url)) ;
        {
            SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
            var userLoginName = user.LoginName;
            SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
            var profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
            var userProfile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(userLoginName);
            var name = userProfile.DisplayName.ToString();
            var BirthDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(userProfile["SPS-Birthday"].Value).ToLocalTime();
            var HireDate = Convert.ToDateTime(userProfile["SPS-HireDate"].Value).ToLocalTime();
            var dataDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            var Ul = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
            var List1= new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            var List2= new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            var List3= new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            List1.InnerText = "Name: " + name.ToString();
            List2.InnerText = "Birthday: " + BirthDateTime;
            List3.InnerText = "Hire date: " + HireDate;
            Ul.Controls.Add(List1);
            Ul.Controls.Add(List2);
            Ul.Controls.Add(List3);
            dataDiv.Controls.Add(Ul); 
            Controls.Add(dataDiv); 
        }
```

Code to retrieve all users data from current site

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
        {
            SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
            UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
            var dataDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            var Ul = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
            foreach (UserProfile profile in profileManager)
            {
                var name = profile.DisplayName.ToString();
                var BirthDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(profile["SPS-Birthday"].Value).ToLocalTime();
                var HireDate = Convert.ToDateTime(profile["SPS-HireDate"].Value).ToLocalTime();
                var List1= new HtmlGenericControl("li");
                List1.InnerText = "Name: " + name.ToString();
                var List2= new HtmlGenericControl("li");
                List2.InnerText = "Birthday: " + BirthDateTime;
                var List3= new HtmlGenericControl("li");
                List3.InnerText = "Hire date: " + HireDate;
                Ul.Controls.Add(List1);
                Ul.Controls.Add(List2);
                Ul.Controls.Add(List3);
            }                
            dataDiv.Controls.Add(Ul); 
            Controls.Add(dataDiv);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code demonstrates how can we fetch Active Directory (AD) using Directory Service. For this, I'm using object array (Users) and here is the structure:

```
public class Users
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public bool isMapped { get; set; }
}
```

**The code below shows how to fetch user information from Active Directory.**

```
public List<Users> GetADUsers()
{
    try
    {
        List<Users> lstADUsers = new List<Users>();
        string DomainPath = "LDAP://DC=xxxx,DC=com"
        DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(DomainPath); 
        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
        search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("usergroup");
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname");//first name
        SearchResult result;
        SearchResultCollection resultCol = search.FindAll();
        if (resultCol != null)
        {
            for (int counter = 0; counter < resultCol.Count; counter++)
            {
                string UserNameEmailString = string.Empty;
                result = resultCol[counter];
                if (result.Properties.Contains("samaccountname") && 
                         result.Properties.Contains("mail") && 
                    result.Properties.Contains("displayname"))
                {
                    Users objSurveyUsers = new Users();
                    objSurveyUsers.Email = (String)result.Properties["mail"][0] + 
                      "^" + (String)result.Properties["displayname"][0];
                    objSurveyUsers.UserName = (String)result.Properties["samaccountname"][0];
                    objSurveyUsers.DisplayName = (String)result.Properties["displayname"][0];
                    lstADUsers.Add(objSurveyUsers);
                }
            }
        }
        return lstADUsers;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

}
```

Above is the sample code to get `Mail`, `UserGroup` & `Display Name`.

If you need all the information than kindly follow steps mentioned below article.

[ALL Operations on Active Directory (AD) using c#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/all-operations-on-active-directory-ad-using-C-Sharp/)

Comment: these all mensioned columns are synched or mapped you can check that here [https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147510.aspx] and i want to retrieve no mapped columns value

Comment: Means you need Birthday from AD? Is there such attribute in your AD?

Comment: If it is your custom attribute than you need to check if property exist or not...Kindly check here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927309/retrieving-custom-active-directory-properties-of-users

Comment: If you want to map the Birthday SharePoint field to AD than please check this...http://jantjesworld.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-map-birthday-sharepoint-field-to.html